# Syntax Error for MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

I created a simple trigger as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_update_rche_prep` BEFORE UPDATE ON `rche_prep` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.case_number = 'ABC';
```

Which is working, when I want to add the `BEGIN...END` syntax to it, like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_update_rche_prep` BEFORE UPDATE ON `rche_prep` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.case_number = 'ABC';
END;
```

It fails, I have no idea why this will happen, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_update_rche_prep` BEFORE UPDATE ON `rche_prep` 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
   SET NEW.case_number = 'ABC';
 END;//
DELIMITER ;
```